# Facet query returning 100 items max

Tags: solr, content-search, search-facet

Using Sitecore 9.2 with Solr on SearchStax. We have the Query.MaxItems value patched to 0, so finding a limit returned of 100 items is unexpected. We're setting up a number of dropdowns, using this code to get the values as facets:

```
var resultsFacets = repository.SearchByPredicate(query)
            .FacetOn(x => x.Schools, minCount)
            .Take(0)
            .GetResults();
```

Followed by this call:

```
FacetCategory schools = resultsFacets.Facets.Categories.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.Equals("schools", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

There's some additional code that assembles it into the dropdown list, but this search code is what's returning the values, and again only 100. So what I can't figure is why I'm only getting 100 items, if there's another setting that needs overriding to bypass a 100 result limit because of the facets call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/2367

Solr has a limit on the number of facets - which has nothing to do with the `Query.MaxItems` btw (that is for Sitecore queries). You should be able to set `facet.limit` to -1 to get all results.

Not sure if in the current implementation by Sitecore there is another solution possible already, but this was given at the community site answer mentioned above:

> On your Solr Server, edit the solrconfig.xml for the index you are
> using. It is found in the conf folder of your index.
>
> Find the requesthandler you are using, for instance "/select", and add
> -1. Be aware that you have to do this
> for each index that you want to update.
>
> For me it looks like this after the fix:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler"> 
<!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these will be
overridden by parameters in the request --> 
<lst name="defaults"> 
<str name="echoParams">explicit</str> 
<int name="rows">10</int> 
<str name="df">text</str> 
<str name="facet.limit">-1</str> 
</lst>
```

One more blog with the same solution explained: https://blog.ryanbailey.co.nz/2018/07/sitecore-experience-commerce-facets-are.html

Comment: My hunting and pecking seems to suggest this as well. Since it's SearchStax I think we'll have to open a support ticket to make the change. Thanks!