# Docker Solr - set facet limit using solrconfig.xml

Tags: solr, docker, search-facet

I am running `Sitecore 10.2` in `Docker`. I have a custom index and need  100 facets from search result. I found a solution in `Solr` documentation. It suggest to raise a limit by changing `solrconfig.xml`. Got one more article taking about its solution:
[Facet query returning 100 items max](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/25790/facet-query-returning-100-items-max)

Any idea how to set a facet limit in a Docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. https://sitecore.namics.com/custom-solr-indexes-and-config-sets-in-sitecore-docker-containers/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanky you very much, Adam.